# CloudFront: 403 We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to Terraform / CloudFront. I have a website that attempts to serve an index.html page from an S3 "website" bucket. However, when you visit this webpage, it produces a 403. If you check the headers (and the body of the error), it appears to be coming from CloudFront. There is also a second error that surfaced about cipher mismatches, but I'm unable to reproduce that at the moment (might be related?).

The CloudFront distribution has been written in Terraform, but the S3 bucket was manually stood up. I am using a `custom_origin` as that was required for an S3 "website" (honestly, I haven't yet understood the difference between a plain S3 bucket and an S3 "website). Below is the Terraform code for the Cloudfront distribution:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "acm_sschi_certificate" {
  domain_name       = "*.mysite.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_mysite_distribution" {
  comment             = "mysite.com CloudFront Distribution"
  enabled             = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn      = aws_acm_certificate.acm_mysite_certificate.arn
    ssl_support_method       = "sni-only"
    minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.2_2021"
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    target_origin_id       = "mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    allowed_methods        = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods         = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    compress               = false
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = var.mysite-website-bucket-s3
    origin_id   = var.mysite-website-bucket-origin-id
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = 80
      https_port             = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
      origin_read_timeout    = 60
    }
  }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  aliases = ["www.mysite.com"]

  # Enable CloudFront logging
  logging_config {
    bucket          = var.mysite-website-logging-bucket
    include_cookies = false                            
    prefix          = "CDN/"                          
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any information that could point me in the right direction? So far I've tried running through this [list from AWS](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-troubleshoot-403-errors). I can confirm the following:

1. [This bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html) is set.
2. WAF is not enabled
3. No geological restrictions
4. The viewer protocol policy is configured for `http-only`, but only because [AWS docs told me to do so for an S3 "website" bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html) (see second "important" note).
5. This is not a signed request
6. The domain name (mysite.com) in this example, has an issued ACM certificate for *.mysite.com

I'm really stuck on this one! If anyone could help, I would appreciate it greatly.